# Qlikview Field dependencies

Tags: dependencies, field, qlikview

Is there a way to disable the field autocomplete in [qlikview](/questions/tagged/qlikview)? For example, I have a document with 3 tables, and an object that has X fields, used for filtering data. 
My problem is that when selecting a value for a field, [qlikview](/questions/tagged/qlikview) automatically completes the dependent fields (either pre-selects the only valid value in relation to what I selected, or disables the values in the list that are not compatible with the my selection).

I'm working on a software that works with Qlikview OCX and I generate a form on the UI with those X fields. If user selects a Code and let's say a Date that in [qlikview](/questions/tagged/qlikview) is not suitable for that code, the following scenario will happen: my algorithm selects the Code, OK, then it selects the invalid date, and [qlikview](/questions/tagged/qlikview) will replace the selected code with a compatible one, and set the date.

So my question is: is there a way to disable this behaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to disable this behavior, this is what sells Qlikview, it's a associative BI tool.

There is a workaround though, just right click on your object/chart/table and click on detach. Or you can have your data not associate to each other.